# Set global variable / text direction in Laravel middleware

Tags: laravel

I have a middleware that reads the language setting from the database and applies the sets the application locale accordingly:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    $lang = SystemSetting::find('System Language');
    \App::setLocale($lang->value);

    return $next($request);
}
```

I would also like to set the text direction (rtl or ltr) so it will be available to my blade template in order to load the necessary css files.

I can easily do it in the controller but i do not wish to repeat it in every controller and pass it to the view for every page in my application. Is there a way to set a global variable or something similar so I can do this in my blade template:

```
    @if ($RTL)
    {{ Html::style('css/rtl/app-rtl.css') }}
    @else 
    {{ Html::style('css/app.css') }}
    @endif
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the view facade, that you can read more about [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#passing-data-to-views).

This allows you to directly prepare any data for the views and make it available there.

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    $lang = SystemSetting::find('System Language');
    \App::setLocale($lang->value);

    View::share('rtl', true);

    return $next($request);
}
```

But I would suggest looking into flashing this [into the session.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session)

Comment: But if I flash it to the session, don't I still have to pass it from the controller to the view?
I flash status messages to the sessions and still pass them from the controller.

Comment: @Patriot Ah, right yes. Since you are using blade you could also just get the value from the session facade in the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can change with translation

```
<html lang="{{config('app.locale')}}" dir="{{@trans('interface.dir')}}">
```

interface in ar file :

```
 return [
 //add this line in ar file
'dir' =>'rtl', 
]
```

interface in en file :

```
  return [
//add this line in en file
    'dir' =>'ltr',
    ]
```